# PostgreSQL query with two inner joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Not great with SQL queries, need a little help to get a working query with two inner joins.

Here's my tables:

posts
users
orgs

posts/users share a key of "user_id" which allows me to pull the posts table and have it also include the username of the user from the users table. I need to pull more data though.. I need to also include the "org_id" from the users table and then pull in the corresponding row from the orgs table.

Currently my SQL query is

```
SELECT p.*, u.username FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users u
ON p.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
```

and this correctly gets me the full list of posts stored in the posts table and includes the username.

I need it to include data from the orgs table.

So if Post #1 is created by user #2, I get that info together. How can I have it do another inner join that takes user #2 and gets the full set of data from the user's corresponding org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it correctly, the query would be the following:

```
SELECT p.*, u.username,o.* FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users u
ON p.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN orgs o
ON u.org_id=o.org_id
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
```

You can *learn more about joins* [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

You can join any number of tables as you want in the same way. Please try now :

```
SELECT p.*,o.*, u.username FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users u
    ON p.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN ORGS O 
    ON u.org_id = o.org_id 
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
```

More examples can be found [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/).

Comment: Thaaaaank you! This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there. Just add the `orgs` table in another join condition:

```
SELECT p.*, o.*, u.username FROM posts p
INNER JOIN users u
ON p.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN orgs o
ON o.org_id = u.org_id
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed!